# SSRS 2008 UserID field caching old Active Directory user id

Tags: reporting-services, active-directory, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008, and there is a Built-in Field called User!UserID that says it returns "The ID of the user running the report."

I'm using this field to limit parameter options that are shown to whichever user is accessing the report.

We have a user who recently changed her last name.  What's happening is when she runs this report, a SQL trace shows it is still passing in her old user id with her old last name.  It's like SSRS hasn't updated from Active Directory yet or something.

Has anyone else run into something like this or have any ideas? Our DBA says he found some references to restarting the SSRS services but since this is a production system that's going to take coordination, plus it seems like name changes have to be relatively common anyway and it's hard to believe no one else has run across this before.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Delete report from SSRS manager and Re-Deploy the report. I had issue like that before.

Comment: Please start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524276/problem-with-default-parameters-in-ssrs-report

Comment: Thanks @Hiten004, I don't know that it's an issue of the parameter default not being set though, but I had run across advice to delete and redeploy.  It "feels" like (I hate that!) the SSRS server has not had the AD change propagate down yet, or it's stuck or something. Is there documentation of what/how SSRS's User!UserID field actually works?

Comment: Did you try to ReDeploy?

Comment: To answer one of you questions, yes, I am experiencing the same thing. Nothing suggested here so far has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would restart the SSRS service.  This typically takes less than 30 seconds so its not a a serious outage. Also ensure the user has restarted her PC since the AD change, in case it is caching her credentials.