# Why does my SSRS Reports show the old descriptions?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have uploaded one SSRS report with a description and another one without a description. When I change/add the description on both reports, for some reason the report that already has a description does not have its description updated. The one without the description however, gets its description updated just fine.

So what I had to do is delete the report from the server and reupload it. This will allow the descriptions to be shown properly.

Why is this happening and is there a configuration setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

[Issue re-deploying updated default parameters in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524276/issue-re-deploying-updated-default-parameters-in-ssrs-report)

Please see the above link and answer from Dining Philanderer (https://stackoverflow.com/users/30934/dining-philanderer)